# check if item is at first position from within ListView adapter during scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView. Inside the adapter, when I do the following (code below), the `firstVisible` is only equal to `position` when the list first displays. During scrolling, when the view is visibly at the top, the adapter is still not capturing it as being at the top.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
        int firstVisible = ((ListView) parent).getFirstVisiblePosition();
            if (firstVisible == position) {/
                //print some stuff and do work
            } else {
                //print some other stuff and do other work
            }
        }
        return rowView;
    }
```

So my question is, how do I track when a specific item is at the top of the ListView during scrolling? And I want to do that from within the adapter.

**EDIT**

When the view in question reaches the top: first I want to set it to GONE so that it is not visible. In fact if I can only do that, that would be great. Then I want to grab its data for some work.

Comment: it depends on what you mean by "at the top" can you define that better? because if just a sliver of the previous view is visible. also that code will only get executed when getView gets called, it sounds like you want to change an existing view if it gets scrolled to the top am I correct?

Comment: @Eluvatar, Yes and no. I want to change some of the data inside the view; but I also want to do some other work based on the old data that was in the view. All when it reaches the top.

Comment: @Eluvatar,  actually thanks for your question. I have clarified.

Answer (score 3):

ok I think I've got a solution:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    ListView             listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int firstVisible;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                processView(v, getItem(position), true);
                return v;
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            adapter.add("Value " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
        }

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        firstVisible = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem != firstVisible) {
                    onFirstVisibleChanged(firstVisible, firstVisibleItem);
                    firstVisible = firstVisibleItem;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void processView(View v, String value, boolean fromGetView) {
        //if from get view we don't want to set yet wait till it comes from scrolling
        if (value.contains("4") && !fromGetView) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_orange_light);
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
    }

    private void onFirstVisibleChanged(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        View v = getViewForPosition(newIndex);
        String val = adapter.getItem(newIndex);
        processView(v, val, false);
    }

    /**
     * @param position
     *            position of item in list
     * @return null if position outside bounds
     */
    public View getViewForPosition(int position) {
        int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - listView.getHeaderViewsCount();
        int wantedChild = position - firstPosition;
        // Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild will now be 2
        // So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
        if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= listView.getChildCount()) {
            return null;
        }
        return listView.getChildAt(wantedChild);
    }
}
```

the best way for me to explain what to do was just to try it myself.

what this does is make a list of strings "Value n" up to 30
if the string contains the number 4 when scrolling we will change the background color to orange. If you want the view to be removed we should be able to do that like this:

```
private void processView(View v, String value, boolean fromGetView) {
    //if from get view we don't want to set yet wait till it comes from scrolling
    if (value.contains("4") && !fromGetView) {
        adapter.remove(value);
    } else {
        //no action needed
    }
}
```

however this could be very confusing to the user as the moment Value 4 gets to the top it is removed and value 5 takes it's place.

Answer (score 1):

`getView` is called before the view is visible, so when you scroll down, most of the time `position` will be `firstVisible - 1` and when you scroll up `firstVisible + totalVisibleItems`.

Instead you should bind a scroll listener to your ListView

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
      // Here you can change the model of the firstView and invalidate it for her to be redrawn
    }
});
```

Comment: Please see my clarifying update. I have already done as you suggested but that has not worked for making the view GONE.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to make the view GONE. If you do, the next view will be at the top, will be GONE, and so on... Can you give further details ?

Comment: No. It's not like that. The view I am watching has a certain data value in it. (each view has different data value though the same data type). When that data value reaches the top, then I want to set the related view to GONE.

Comment: Can't you just remove the related item from the List or so bound to the ListView and call notifyDataSetChanged() against its Adapter ?